Angular 17 SSR iframe CORP issue
When an Angular app is created with the new built-in SSR, I can't use iframes because CORP isn't being set.
I tried a standard app without SSR, and iframes work perfectly, but for the SSR app, I can't set CORS.
Angular CLI: 17.1.2
Node: 20.9.0
NPM: 10.2.3
Package versions are all 17.1.2
Update:
Issue was i have modified angular.json configuration header which was preventing COEP and COOP headers.
"headers": {
                "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
                "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin"
              }

This should be done from server side.
